# Find mismatched records using shared field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm a Splunk newb and am wrestling with building a specific query. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the base search.

```
index=index (Food="*meat*") AND (Food="*veggie*" OR Food="*fruit*")
```

From here, I rex the result and sort.

```
| rex field=_raw "location \((?<Farm>\w+)\).*operator \((?<Farmer>\w+)\).*crops \((?<CropType>\w+)\).*"
| stats list(Farm), list(CropType), count by Farmer
| sort -count
```

This is a good start, but it returns way more than needed, and I'm getting way out in the weeds with this.  Here's the details:

- **CropType** contains two possible values, *veggie* or *fruit*.
- I only want to see records where one veggie and one fruit share the same Farm.  (No fruit/fruit, veggie/veggie.)

The end goal here is to present a list of farms and crops per farmer.

Thanks in advance for any assistance/insight.

Comment: what does your raw data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
index=index (Food="*meat*") AND (Food="*veggie*" OR Food="*fruit*")
| rex field=_raw "location \((?<Farm>\w+)\).*operator \((?<Farmer>\w+)\).*crops \((?<CropType>\w+)\).*"
| eval fruitFarm=if(CropType=="fruit",1,0)
| eval vegFarm=if(CropType=="veggie",1,0)
| stats sum(fruitFarm) as fruitFarm, sum(vegFarm) as vegFarm by Farm, Farmer
| where fruitFarm>0 and vegFarm>0
```